# Change afArrayField header - Meteor Autoform

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I want to adjust the header text for certain array fields. All I've thought to attempt is changing the label in the schema, but that didn't have and affect as far as I can tell.

```
...
address:{
  type: [Schemas.address],
  optional: true,
  defaultValue: [],
  autoform:{
    label:"Add your addresses"
  }
},
...
```

Simply shows "address". For reference, the form template adds header like so:

```
{{afFieldLabelText name=this.atts.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#label

label attribute should not be nested in autoform. See code below:

`MySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    label: function () {
      return Session.get("lang") == "de"
            ? "Vorname" : "first name";
    }
  }
});`